# popup inside the same page

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I need to show a page of contents inside my page.

ie; when i click on a link it will show 2 paragraphs inside a div as popup in the same page.

that popup must have a close button in it to close that div popup.

Is any one have an idea or code to help me in this

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use hide properties for your div tag.

For hiding

```
document.getElementById('divid').style.display='none';
```

For displaying

```
document.getElementById('divid').style.display='block';
```

Comment: @tibin mathew, you need it to be a pop-up (as in a separate window that opens up above the web-page) or you want it to be a light-box/modal dialogue (a hidden `div` that pops up, but is *a part of the web-page itself*)? The code given by @pavun_cool would achieve the second aim.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like a jQuery modal dialogue box:

- <del>[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)</del> - apparently no longer maintained.
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), recommended by those behind Thickbox.
- [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)
- [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)
- [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox), which looks much as you'd expect, from the name...